# How to produce a valid Pkcs11UriBuilder based on the current smartcard

Tags: c#, smartcard, pkcs11interop

I do have a smartcard from thales/gemalto which I can access via their SafeNet software.
[image]

I'm using [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop) for accessing the smartcard via c#. I am able to read the basic information and also can login using the pin via c#.

I now need to create an instance of Pkcs11UriBuilder. There is also an example for this on the Pkcs11Interop [website](https://www.pkcs11interop.net/extensions/uri/_pkcs11_uri_and_builder_example_8cs-example.html)

```
// ...or it can be easily constructed with Pkcs11UriBuilder
Pkcs11UriBuilder pkcs11UriBuilder = new Pkcs11UriBuilder();
pkcs11UriBuilder.Serial = "123456";
pkcs11UriBuilder.Type = CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY;
pkcs11UriBuilder.Object = "TestApp";
pkcs11UriBuilder.ModulePath = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\eTPKCS11.dll";
pkcs11UriBuilder.PinValue = "MyPin";
```

The following values are dependent of the smartcard:

- Serial
- Object

The serial I can get via the following code:

```
ITokenInfo tokenInfo = slot.GetTokenInfo();
var serial = tokenInfo.SerialNumber;
```

Question: What value must be provided to "Object" and how do I read the possible/available Object value from the SmartCard using Pkcs11Interop?